# Cmd key not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

The left <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key on my MacBook Pro is not working, the right one does. It seems like it is a software problem with Mavericks. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: What makes you think it's a software problem? Mine works fine under Mavericks, and I'm fairly sure if there were a common problem it'd have been widely reported & fixed by now...

Comment: Did it stop working right after you upgraded?